# Specify multiple filters in hbase

Tags: java, hbase

Is there a way to specify multiple filters during a scan? For example - Specify both a `ColumnFamilyFilter` and `RowFilter`?

```
Filter rowFilter =
                new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new RegexStringComparator(
                        rowFilterString));
        Scan s = new Scan();
        s.setFilter(rowFilter);
```

I wanted to also add a `ColumnFilter` to `s`. But it obviously overrides the latest filter.

Answer (score 26):

You have to create a [FilterList](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) object, and add all the filters you want to that, and set this `FilterList` object as the filter. You can either use the constructor or use the `addFilter()` method to add filters to the filter list.

```
FilterList filterList = new FilterList();
filterList.addFilter(new RowFilter(...));
filterList.addFilter(new ColumnFilter(...));
Scan s = new Scan();
s.setFilter(filterList);
```

Answer (score 8):

if you are adding multiple filters then do remember that by default filterlist uses

```
FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL
```

which means all filter must be passed (AND condition).
Use

```
FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE
```

if you want to apply OR condition for filters.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the FilterList object to add your list of filters and can control the order of filters using an ArrayList. Each FilterList takes in only a single operator[OR, AND].But, an hierarchy of filter lists can be created by adding multiple filter list instances with their own operators to a parent filter list.

For example:
filters_1 & filters_2 are two filter lists.

```
FilterList filterList1 = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE,filters_1);
FilterList filterList2 = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL,filters_2);


List<Filter> filterAggregate = new ArrayList<>();
filterAggregate.add(filterList1);
filterAggregate.add(filterList2);

FilterList filterList3 = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL,filterAggregate);
```